# Failed to insert data into the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

First, I pick data from the session. and these data I trying to transfer to another model. but is my first data(session) is uploaded successfully into the database.first data transfer is successful. but the second third fourth whatever, those data can't transfer my model.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Checkout(Order11 anOrder) {
    List<Shop> shop = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Shop>>("shop");

    for (int i = 0; i < shop.Count(); i++) {
        if (shop != null) {
            anOrder.ProductName = shop[i].Name;
            anOrder.ImagePath = shop[i].Image;
            anOrder.Price = shop[i].Price;
            anOrder.Quantity = shop[i].Quantity;

            anOrder.OrderNo = GetOrderNo();

            _db.Order11.Add(anOrder);
        }

        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    // other code
}
```

Order11.cs

```
  public class Order11
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Order Number")]
        public string OrderNo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public int Price { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

When I run the application then I get this error:

[image]

I want to transfer all sessions data into my model(DB). What's the solution to this problem? I am a beginner please help.

Comment: the key property of `anOrder` is not a default value (meaning it's assigned to some valid non-zero value). I suppose its key may be `Id` which is auto-incremented (auto-generated by db), should not be explicitly assigned a value. You should have a check for that. If it's meant to be added, the key property should be ignored by resetting it back to the zero value (e.g: `0` for int) before adding it to the `DbContext`.

Comment: @Hopeless where should I change this code..

Comment: right at the very beginning of your method `Checkout`, also try debugging first to see if it's like what I said. However you should also find out why the key property is assigned to some non-zero value before the entity is passed in your method here, that way you may find something wrong earlier in the execution flow. If setting it back to zero is fine anyway, just do it.

Comment: Can you post the `Order11` model so that it's clean what is your identity column

Comment: Note that, you must fully understand the effect of this method, should the passed-in order be always added (created) or sometimes updated? In case of updating, you need to write some `if` to attach it to the `DbContext` ***correctly***, calling `Add` is one way to attach the entity to the `DbContext` with a state of `Added`. Usually if the key property is a non-zero value, it's a sign of updating, otherwise adding.

Comment: when you call the CheckOut method at ajax call or another, do you set the Id value for the Order11 parameter? just add a breakpoint to the CheckOut method and when it hits, check anOrder object's Id value, if it has value then you must not send it at your call

Comment: @user1672994 I updated my post. here I have given the order11 model. please check it.

Comment: @Hopeless can I try a ViewModel instead of  order11? I found many properties value in "anorder"..if I use this "anOrder" ViewModel type instead of Order11.is this will work perfectly which I want?

Comment: @MehmetY. yes, I set many values here. what process i have to follow for transfer?

Comment: @BrettLee of course you set value for multiple properties, but the point here is the key property value (as in the model class you posted, it's the `Id`). Do you see any assigned value for that `Id`? Using ViewModel is just another way to design your method, the problem is to understand your goal, what the method does, what it needs and what the output effect is (as I've already commented above).

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ I added a 3 count value. just one count value is added to my model(order11) successfully, but 2nd and 3rd count values could not be added.

Comment: @Hopeless No, I debugged here and found Id=0

Comment: @BrettLee the `Id` is generated after the first loop, so the error you see is thrown at the second loop. I miss the point you put the `SaveChanges` in the loop. That does not make sense at all. You're doing things wrong in many aspects, and now I don't understand what you actually want here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Set `anOrder.Id = 0;` before saving the data.

Comment: the code would work with this added but the OP may not even know if its effect is desired/expected, e.g: later on he may find out that some orders should be updated but instead added (cloned as duplicates) =))

Comment: The OP is saving the same model in loop. After first save itself the ID will be updated with the primary key value. Hence it is required to reset the Id to 0 everytime savechanges() is called.

Comment: ah I see, missing that point. So his code looks like a cloning job (from one entity passed in). That still may not be what he wants.

Comment: There is definitely a design flaw here. But I'm not judging.

Answer (score 1):

Show please inner exception using try, catch. I cannot comment.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Checkout(Order11 anOrder)
{
List<Shop> shop = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Shop>>("shop");

for (int i = 0; i < shop.Count(); i++)
{
    try
    {
    if (shop != null)
    {
        anOrder.ProductName = shop[i].Name;
        anOrder.ImagePath = shop[i].Image;
        anOrder.Price = shop[i].Price;
        anOrder.Quantity = shop[i].Quantity;

        anOrder.OrderNo = GetOrderNo();

        _db.Order11.Add(anOrder);
    }

    _db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

// other code
}
```